# get customer active days from mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb document for customer streaming activations.

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "email": "customer1@email.com",
    "packageid": "movies",
    "command": "activated",
    "tid": "123",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-06-08")
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "email": "customer2@email.com",
    "packageid": "movies",
    "command": "activated",
    "tid": "124",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-06-20")
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "email": "customer1@email.com",
    "packageid": "movies",
    "command": "deactivated",
    "tid": "1234",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-06-10")
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "email": "customer2@email.com",
    "packageid": "movies",
    "command": "deactivated",
    "tid": "1244",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-06-22")
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "email": "customer1@email.com",
    "packageid": "movies",
    "command": "activated",
    "tid": "123",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-06-11")
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "email": "customer2@email.com",
    "packageid": "movies",
    "command": "activated",
    "tid": "1244",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-06-23")
  },
  {
    "_id": 7,
    "email": "customer1@email.com",
    "packageid": "movies",
    "command": "deactivated",
    "tid": "1237",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-06-15")
  },
  {
    "_id": 8,
    "email": "customer2@email.com",
    "packageid": "movies",
    "command": "deactivated",
    "tid": "1244",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-06-25")
  },
  
]
```

now I wanna group by email and get each customer activated days for specific time frame. let's say 1 month. I've been trying this for few hours

```
{
"email":"customer1@email.com"
"packageid":"movies",
"days": 3
},
{
"email":"customer1@email.com"
"packageid":"movies",
"days": 5
},
{
"email":"customer2@email.com"
"packageid":"movies",
"days": 3
},
{
"email":"customer2@email.com"
"packageid":"movies",
"days": 3
}
```

edit: any user can activate then deactivate the service any time they want sometimes users do activate and deactivate multiple times within a same month.
I want to find out how many days customer was activated.

Comment: Can you elaborate slightly more what is the expected output? can users have multiple activations and deactiations? how you want to deal with that?

Comment: Not clear what you try to get. [$dateDiff](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/) could be a starting point

Comment: Agree with @TomSlabbaert. Further input is required from OP. At status quo, the best we can do should be something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UW0FwH-Wge5)

Comment: @TomSlabbaert yes. users can have multiple activations and deactivations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `$setWindowFields` to compute the `$dateDiff` and `$group` the sum.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": {
        email: "$email",
        packageid: "$packageid"
      },
      "sortBy": {
        "createdAt": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "next": {
          $shift: {
            output: "$createdAt",
            by: 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "command": "activated"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      email: "$email",
      packageid: "$packageid",
      "days": {
        "$dateDiff": {
          startDate: "$createdAt",
          endDate: {
            $ifNull: [
              "$next",
              "$$NOW"
            ]
          },
          unit: "day"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OkLPAnTVE6_) for your reference.

Comment: that's so cool. thanks. how can I check activate changed date. let's say some customer active since oct 1st to oct 25th now state is "deactivate" how can I check that customer's active state days?

Comment: @LahiruSupun better update your question with the expected output. Currently, it is unclear what you are asking for.